# rails - Do I need to sanitize text input if its not being written to the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I built a "send us a message" form on a recent site.  The message isn't stored to the database, rather its parameterized and sent via ActionMailer.  Other than this form the only other visitor facing form is the login form.

What I'm wondering is this: Should I be sanitizing the content from the contact form?

thanks for helping a noob!

Comment: By sanitize you mean doing validation against the entered data? I would always validate any input at both the client and server level to remove any potential malicious code. Even if it is sent by an ActionMailer, you would not want a user to be able to inject javascript into the e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always think it is best practice to sanitize all data before doing anything with it. Even if you aren't storing it in the database directly it still is best practice to do some sort of sanitizing it because it can still affect the user you are sending the email to.

1. Never trust user input.
2. Escape as late as possible.
3. Escape everything from untrusted sources (like databases and users),
   third-parties (like Twitter), etc.
4. Never assume anything.
5. Never trust user input.
6. Sanitation is okay, but validation/rejection is
   better.
7. Never trust user input.

hopefully one thing stands out to you.